# how to find the parameters of the orthogonal line of a found one in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a program that find lines in a frame actually I have only one, I'm trying to find "some" line that are orthogonal to the found one:

```
............................
cv::HoughLines(canny,lineQ,1,CV_PI/180,200);

    for( size_t i = 0; i < lineQ.size(); i++ )
        {
          float rho = lineQ[i][0], theta = lineQ[i][1];
          cv::Point pt1, pt2;
          double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
          double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
          pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
          pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
          pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
          pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));

          angle =(-1)* atan2f((pt2.y-pt1.y),(pt2.x-pt1.x))* 180.0/CV_PI;  // getting the angle of the lines 
            lineFunction(angle, mask,rho,pt1,theta);  // this function should draw the othogonal line 


line( mask, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);

...........
```

here is the function in which I'm try to find the orthogonal one :

```
void lineFunction(float alpha,cv::Mat frame,float rho,cv::Point Pt3,float omega){
    float b = 0.0;  
    float newAlpha = 0.0 ; 
    float newRho = 0.0;
    cv::Point pt1, pt2;
    if(alpha != 90.0 && alpha !=0.0 && alpha!=-90.0){
    b =  (Pt3.x * (-1)) + rho/sinf(alpha);
    if( alpha <0){
        newAlpha = CV_PI + omega;
        newRho = b+sinf(newAlpha);

          double a = cos(newAlpha), b = sin(newAlpha);
      double x0 = a*newRho, y0 = b*newRho;
      pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
      pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
      pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
      pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));

    }else if ( alpha > 0 ) {
        newAlpha = CV_PI - omega;
        newRho = b+sinf(newAlpha);

          double a = cos(newAlpha), b = sin(newAlpha);
      double x0 = a*newRho, y0 = b*newRho;
      pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
      pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
      pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
      pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
    }
     line( frame, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 3, CV_AA);
    }
}
```

and this the result that I  get, the red line has been found and green one should be calculated

[image: result]

any Idea what I'm doing wrong ?

thanks a lot for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played with the function `lineFunction` and it work now, I hope this will help somebody:

```
void lineFunction(float alpha,cv::Mat frame,float rho,cv::Point pt,float omega){
    float winkel=0;
    float distance;
    // calculating the new angle 
    if( alpha !=0.0 && alpha!=90.0 && alpha!=90.0){
        //if( alpha<0){
        winkel = CV_PI/2+omega;
        distance = (pt.x*cosf(winkel))+ (pt.y *sin(winkel));
        cv::Point pt1, pt2;
          double a = cos(winkel), b = sin(winkel);
          double x0 = a*distance, y0 = b*distance;
          pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
          pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
          pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
          pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
          line( frame, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 3, CV_AA);
    }
}
```

here is what I get :   [image: result]

Answer (score 1):

You convert your angle from radians to degrees before passing to lineFunction, the cos and sin functions in there should be working on radians I believe.

Comment: yes 1 it true I figured it out but it didn't help , but thanks for you answer

Comment: Ok, if it still doesn't work could you give more clarification about how it doesn't work and what exactly you're trying to do?